# Objective C custom class methods not being called

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, class

So I have this custom class with just a test method that does nslog.  I am going to reuse this method many times in my app.  The interface looks like this.

```
@interface TestViewController: UIViewController {  CMImageMover * imageMover }
```

Then in the view did load I:

```
imageMover = [[CmImageMover alloc] init];
```

If I do:

```
[imageMover testMethod];
```

Right after the alloc and init it works in the viewDidLoad function but if I call it again from another function in the view controller nothing works and the class method does not get called.

What am I doing wrong here.  Every other var I declare like NSArray/NSTimer, I do the say way and I am able to access and use it throughout my controller.

Comment: could you provide the body of a function that isn't managing to call testMethod?

Comment: You should show us the calling code. And is it a "class method" or "instance method"?

Comment: The method in the class is this: 
    - (void) testM {
        NSLog(@"in test");
    }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say "if I call it again from another function in the view controller nothing works" then first thing to check is what you are sending the `testMethod`. It could be nil, in which case nothing will happen. In objective C sending a message to nil does nothing. Add an NSLog to find out, e.g.

```
 NSLog(@"imageMover object is: %@", imageOver);
 [imageMover testMethod];
```

If the NSLog shows it is nil - or something crazy - then follow up what you are doing with the imageMover ivar.

You mention a class method in your question, but don't refer to it in your code snippets.

If you have defined `testMethod` as a class method it will, of course, fail if you send that message to an instance. (And it will fail noisily.) A class method would be introduced like this:

```
 + (void) testMethod
 {
       NSLog(@"CMImageMover testMethod called on Class");
 }
```

An instance method would be introduced like this:

```
 - (void) testMethod
 {
       NSLog(@"testMethod called on an instance of CMImageMover");
 }
```

Apologies if this is all screamingly obvious to you and missing the point of the question. It's not that clear from your question where the issue lies.

Comment: If I do NSLog(@"object is: %@", [imageMover description]); before I call the testMethod it says it's null.

Comment: Ahh I fixed it. So what happened was I have  of a lot things being setup in my viewDidLoad.  I just made that class to I just stuck the alloc and init at the end of viewDidLoad.  The other function calls at the beginning were calling the testmethod before it was allocated.  I moved the alloc and init to the beginning of viewDidLoad and every thing works as it should.  I'm a scatter brain. I marked your as answered because I learned something new with the + class method